# WIX Installer: Removing Files ffrom Web leads to "The system cannot find the file '..'"

Tags: asp.net, wix, windows-installer

so I'm trying to generate a dynamic installer which harvest all the files from the published web project (into `WebComponents.wxs`). It is already working fine but as soon as I delete a file from the `Web.csproj` it gets confused with the generated `WebComponents.wxs`. So my current setup is: when building the `Installer.wixproj` it also builds the `Web.csproj`, which publishes itself for the installer. Adding new files is working fine.

Here is a part from the `Installer.wixproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <WebSiteSource>..\Web\</WebSiteSource>
  <ReleaseWebConfig>Web_setup.config</ReleaseWebConfig>
  <PublishFolderName>app.publish\</PublishFolderName>
  <PublishFolder>..\Web\bin\$(PublishFolderName)</PublishFolder>
  <MsiOut>D:\MA01.ATOUR\src\Installer\bin\Release\VieTour.msi</MsiOut>
  <WebSiteContentCode>WebComponents.wxs</WebSiteContentCode>
  <WebSiteContentObject>WebComponents.wixobj</WebSiteContentObject>
  <WixPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\</WixPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <WixCode Include="$(WebSiteContentCode)" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CreateInstaller" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(WixPath)heat&quot; dir $(PublishFolderName) -dr dirVieTour -ke -srd -cg WebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode)" ContinueOnError="false" WorkingDirectory="." />
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(WixPath)candle&quot; -ext WixIISExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WiXNetFxExtension -dpublishDir=$(PublishFolderName) -dMyWebResourceDir=. @(WixCode, ' ')" ContinueOnError="false" WorkingDirectory="." />
</Target>
```

The generated `WebComponents.wxs` looks something like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="directoryXY">
            <Directory Id="dirEA772C6FDF885BD02D519055C6A5F7D4" Name="bin" />
            <Directory Id="dir9C6C7F6C7D56234126D1F3268C213149" Name="JavaScript" />
            <Directory Id="dir1CD7F397F22159CC91531C851F168C0A" Name="Properties" />
            <Directory Id="dir08FBA1551757E5AA339492A08A61A382" Name="Views" />
            <Directory Id="dirCB77DB5DBF1C1B2953DA0699797F08FC" Name="wwwroot" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="WebComponents">
            <Component Id="cmp2DE1A50D21FA3CFD8D4260FD2285BA4D" Directory="dirVieTour" Guid="{50A1AAC7-F3FC-4A20-9784-B6F24214B4AA}">
                <File Id="fil989DA2FC3E666A81C52CD089644582AF" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\favicon.ico" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp1F31A992017C2787A7EDBD35AF00D862" Directory="dirVieTour" Guid="{0AFAC57B-01A2-404D-966D-524FBD0557B2}">
                <File Id="filF20D2F7FF3255C45551F52F87F2E6D40" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\Global.asax" />
            </Component>
...
```

In the `Product.wxs` I reference the WebComponents:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="WebComponents" />
</Feature>
```

> As soon as I delete a file from the `Web.csproj` and try to build the
> installer I get the following error message:

```
The system cannot find the file 'app.publish\FileThatGotDdeleted'
```

Does anyone know how to handle this in WIX?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to simply republish the web project after you delete the file? I.e. you seem to feed wix from the published files.

Comment: The web project gets republished each time I build the Installer project. I think the problem is that I cannot change the build order from the Installer.wixproj, because in the build output I can see that it always makes candle/light first (light fails then with the error message above, because the heat task is not yet executed and so it cannot find the deleted file)

Comment: To ensure the correct build order (and benefit from other features like source project paths available as variables to wix), you can add reference to your web project to your wix project. In the wix project, click "references", then add, then select your web project. https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html

Comment: I've added that reference and its behaviour didnt change

Comment: Are you sure the publishing happens on build? Because normally it does not, AFAIK (unless you explicitly modified your project file)

Comment: yes I am 100% sure, it also works fine when adding files